# I changed my router and now it takes a while for my Android phone to connect to the Internet

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router, android

I switched routers from a Buffalo WCR-GN to a TP-Link N600 and now it takes a while for my phone to connect to the Internet. At first I thought it was due to my phone (nexus 5) but it's happening with other phones, and even with a factory reset and an update to Lollipop, I'm still encountering this issue.

I have been using a N600 as a wireless access point before, and I've never encountered this issue, so I'm suspecting it's to do with using the N600 as the main router.

To clarify how I've set up the network:

Modem --> TP-Link N600 --> Other routers acting as access points (TP-Link N600, some other buffalo routers)

Before

Modem --> Buffalo WCR-GN --> Other routers acting as access points (TP-Link N600, other buffalo routers)

Devices which work with the routers

- Surface Pro 3
- Desktop computer directly connected to the routers

Devices not working

- Nexus 5 (4.4.4)
- Nexus 5 (Lollipop Dev Preview)
- Galaxy Note
- Galaxy Note 2

The Router can "see" the internet. DHCP Server is disabled on the Access Point routers. DHCP clients list doesn't seem to show any conflicting IP's.

Comment: Do other wireless devices work on the WIFI like a laptop or something? Is your router filtering by mac address? Can you get into the router settings page? Can the router "see" the internet?

Comment: Yes, my computers directly connected to the routers via ethernet cables can connect to the Internet. My Surface Pro 3 is connected to one of the Access Points via wifi.

Comment: Yes, I can get into the router settings. I don't think I've set any MAC filtering. The router can "see the internet".

Comment: I was worried it might be due to conflicting IPs, but according to the DHCP clients list, my phone is the only one being assigned 192.168.0.101, which matches the IP address reported by my phone.

Comment: Well you say "takes awhile to connect" so is it just slow to obtain an IP, is the connection slow once connected, or does it not connect at all? Just wanted to clarify.

Comment: It connects, but I can't access the internet. i.e. I can't load a webpage, google now won't refresh, the wifi icon appears orange (suggesting there's no connection to google) etc.

After a while, it magically works after an indeterminate amount of time (seems to in the range of a few minutes) and I am unsure why. 

It is able to obtain an IP.

Comment: EDIT: actually this is weird. Sometimes when I connect to the Wifi, it is unable to show an IP address on my phone, suggesting that the router has not assigned my phone an IP address yet. However, occasionally it does show that it has obtained an IP address, but it is still unable to connect to the internet. Running a ping test from the router, it times out. After a minute or two, it starts working, I guess the DHCP server finally allocates the IP address and it connects to the internet.

Comment: Edit 2: Ok, while looking at the DHCP clients list on my router, it appears that my phone does get assigned an IP almost immediately, but the phone itself doesn't seem to realise it's got one, and shows "IP Address Unavailable". This is getting annoying.

Comment: From what you said it seems like the problem is on the phone's end but you said it affects more than one phone? That is strange. Which phones are they?

Comment: Devices not working
- Nexus 5 (4.4.4)
- Nexus 5 (Lollipop Dev Preview)
- Galaxy Note
- Galaxy Note 2

Comment: Hm I really have no idea anymore. Sorry Derek